# How to import own module for mocking? (import error: no module named my_module!)

Tags: python, module, mocking

I want to unit test my class, which is in another file named `client_blogger.py`.

My unit test file, is in the same directory. All of my other unit tests work, except when I try to mock one of my own methods.

```
## unit_test_client_blogger.py
import mock
import json

from client_blogger import BloggerClient, requests

Class TestProperties():

    @pytest.fixture

    def blog(self):
    return BloggerClient(api_key='123', url='http://example.com')

    @mock.patch('client_blogger._jload')
    @mock.patch('client_blogger._send_request')

    def test_gets_blog_info(self, mock_send, mock_jload):
    """ Get valid blog info from API response. """

    valid_blog_info = 'some valid json api response here'
    parsed_response = json.loads(valid_blog_info)
    correct_blog_id = '7488272653173849119'
    mock_jload.return_value = valid_blog_info

    id = self.blog().get_blog_info(parsed_response)
    assert id == correct_blog_id
```

And here is the client_blogger.py file contents:

```
# client_blogger.py
import requests, json

class BloggerClient(object):
    """ Client interface for Blogger API. """
    def __init__(self, key, url):
         # removed some code here for brevity

    def _send_request(self, api_request):
        """ Sends an HTTP get request to Blogger API.
            Returns HTTP response in text format. """
        # snip

    def _jload(self, api_response):
        """ Accepts text API response. Returns JSON encoded response. """
        # snip

    def get_blog_info(self):
        """ Makes an API request. Returns Blog item information. """
        request = '{b}/blogs/byurl?url={u}&key={k}'.format(b=self.base, u=self.url, k=self.key)
        txt_response = self.send_request(request)
        response = self._jload(txt_response)
        return response['id']
```

I want to mock out `self.send_request()` and `self._jload()` method calls in the above method.

But Mock module complains: `ImportError: No module named client_blogger`.

The error must lie here:

```
@mock.patch('client_blogger._jload')
@mock.patch('client_blogger._send_request')
```

I've tried many variations in order to get mock.patch to find my module or class. But none of them have worked.

I've tried the following:

```
@mock.patch('client_blogger.BloggerClient._jload')
@mock.patch('BloggerClient._jload')
@mock.patch('._jload')
```

None of those work. Any idea how to mock.patch a method from my own module?

(It seems strange, because I can mock.patch other modules, just not my own :-s)

Answer (score 21):

You want this:

```
@mock.patch('client_blogger.BloggerClient._jload')
@mock.patch('client_blogger.BloggerClient._send_request')
def test_gets_blog_info(self, mock_send, mock_jload):
    """ Get valid blog info from API response. """

    valid_blog_info = 'some valid json api response here'
    parsed_response = json.loads(valid_blog_info)
    correct_blog_id = '7488272653173849119'
    mock_jload.return_value = valid_blog_info

    id = self.blog().get_blog_info(parsed_response)
    assert id == correct_blog_id
```

The `BloggerClient` implementation is coming from the `client_blogger` module, so you need to patch `client_blogger.BloggerClient`. You list that as one of the things you tried that doesn't work, but I just tried it, and it works fine for me. What issue did you have when you tried that?

Comment: +1 I had a related issue the other day, and want to point out that if even if `client_blogger` does not exist in your test module's namespace (because you used `from client_blogger import BloggerClient`), the string `'client_blogger.BloggerClient._jload'` is still correct, not `'BloggerClient._jload'`.

Comment: @dano it still doesn't work for me: `target =     'client_blogger.BloggerClient'ImportError: No module named client_blogger

build\bdist.win32\egg\mock.py:1098: ImportError
===================== 1 failed, 4 passed in 0.23 seconds ======================`

Comment: @chepner I even changed my import line to ' import client_blogger'. Still all fails.

Comment: @dano it worked fine when i deleted my __init__.py file. I thought that file was required (it was empty).

Comment: @user2071506 If you're working within a package, you have to include the package name as well: `@mock.patch('package_name.client_blogger.BloggerClient._jload')`.

Comment: Where is mock_send, mock_jload coming from?

Comment: @SteveB They get added as parameters automatically when you use the two `@mock.patch` decorators on the `test_gets_blog_info` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the file name of the class in the path, before the object name.
e.g. if I have a method named `foo` in a class named `Event` in `tools/event.py` the path will be as follows:

```
patch("tools.event.Event.foo", boo)
```

Answer (score -2):

For python3, the format is as follows:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
@patch('client_blogger.BloggerClient._jload')
.
.
.
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch

This is very, very important:

> patch() is straightforward to use. The key is to do the patching in the right namespace. See the section where to patch.